# OAuth client credentials concept

Tags: oauth-2.0

I just have a question re client_credentials grant type in OAuth 2.0. When a client requests for an access token 2 times, will the access token requested on the first time be invalid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first obtained access token will be valid until it expires.

A token contains an authentication ticket including the indentity and an expiration time. When the token is decrypted, the server obtains the ticket and checks that the ticket is not expired. It uses the claims included in the ticket for authorization tasks.

Comment: ah. so meaning as long as the access token is not yet expired, it can still be used? Even after I request again and again, the previous ones will still work?

Comment: Yes, they do. That's one reason why it is recommended to implement refresh tokens and to have short lived access tokens.

Think that the access token is used to access to a resource server, that is not who generated it and has no way to control how many tokens have been generated for a user.

Besides a user could login from different devices to the same auth server, getting an access token for each device and all of them will be valid until it expires.

Comment: I see. thanks for this. It's just that I was using a library to implement this in my application, then suddenly it didn't work as expected. Now I see that my understanding of the whole OAuth 2.0 process is wrong. Thanks again!